# regular expression to extract JSON string from text

Tags: regex, json, expression

I'm looking for regex to extract json string from text.
 I have the text below, which contains

```
JSON string(mTitle, mPoster, mYear, mDate)
```

like that:

```
{"999999999":"138138138","020202020202":{"846":{"mTitle":"\u0430","mPoster":{"
small":"\/upload\/ms\/b_248.jpg","middle":"600.jpg","big":"400.jpg"},"mYear"
:"2013","mDate":"2014-01-01"},"847":{"mTitle":"\u043a","mPoster":"small":"\/upload\/ms\/241.jpg","middle":"600.jpg","big":"
138.jpg"},"mYear":"2013","mDate":"2013-12-26"},"848":{"mTitle":"\u041f","mPoster":{"small":"\/upload\/movies\/2
40.jpg","middle":"138.jpg","big":"131.jpg"},"mYear":"2013","mDate":"2013-12-19"}}}
```

In order to parse JSON string I should extract JSON string from the text.
That is why, my question: Could you help me to get only JSON string
from text? Please help.

I've tried this regular expression with no success:

```
{"mTitle":(\w|\W)*"mDate":(\w|\W)*}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
\{\s*"mTitle"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"mPoster":\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"mYear"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"mDate"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*\}
```

[Check **demo** here.](http://regexr.com/3a85g)

The main difference from your regex is the `.+?` part, that, broken down, means:

- Match any character (`.`)
- One or more times (`+`)
- As little as possible (`?`)

The `?` operator after the `+` is very important here --- because if you removed it, the first `.+` (in `\{\s*"mTitle"\s*:\s*(.+?)`) would match the whole text, **not** the text up to the `"mPoster"` word, that is what you want.

Notice it is just a more complicated version of `\{"mTitle":(.+?),"mPoster":(.+?),"mYear":(.+?),"mDate":(.+?)\}` (with `\s*` to match spaces, allowed by the JSON notation).